# Get overlapping months in two ranges using date-fns

Tags: javascript, node.js, date-fns

I'm trying to get the overlapping months in two date intervals using [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/):

```js
const range1 = { start: new Date('2018-01-01'), end: new Date('2019-01-01') }
const range2 = { start: new Date('2018-07-03'), end: new Date('2019-12-01') }
getOverlappingMonthsInIntervals(a, b)) // 6
```

Looking at date-fns docs, I see the method `getOverlappingDaysInIntervals` but no similar method for months. Is there a way to achieve this with date-fns or a workaround (other than `getOverlappingDaysInIntervals/30`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create your own overlapping months function using some of the other
[date-fns](https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started) functions. See below for an example.

In my answer I make the assumption that two intervals have an overlapping month
if both intervals span the entirety of that calendar month. Given your example
ranges there are 5 overlapping months: August, September, October, November and
December of 2018.

```
  JFMAMJJASONDJFMAMJJASOND
1 |------+++++|
2       |+++++-----------|
```

1. First we need to determine if the two intervals overlap.

   - This can be done using the [`areIntervalsOverlapping`](https://date-fns.org/v2.9.0/docs/areIntervalsOverlapping) function.
2. If the two intervals overlap then determine the start and end date of the
   where the intervals overlap.

   - If the two intervals overlap, the overlap start date will be the *maximum*
     of the two intervals *start* dates. And, the overlap end date will be the
     *minimum* of the two intervals *end* dates.
   - We can use the [`max`](https://date-fns.org/v2.9.0/docs/max) and [`min`](https://date-fns.org/v2.9.0/docs/min) functions for this.
3. Once we find the start and end of the overlap we need to determine how many
   months are in this interval.

   - We can use the [`differenceInCalendarMonths`](https://date-fns.org/v2.9.0/docs/differenceInCalendarMonths) (or, 
     [`differenceInMonths`](https://date-fns.org/v2.9.0/docs/differenceInMonths)) function for this.

```js
import {
  areIntervalsOverlapping,
  max,
  min,
  // differenceInMonths,
  differenceInCalendarMonths,
} from 'date-fns'

const getOverlappingMonthsInterval = (r1, r2) => {
  if (areIntervalsOverlapping(r1, r2)) {
    const start = max([r1.start, r2.start])
    const end = min([r1.end, r2.end])
    return differenceInCalendarMonths(end, start) // or use `differenceInMonths`
  } else return 0
}

const range1 = { start: new Date('2018-01-01'), end: new Date('2019-01-01') }
const range2 = { start: new Date('2018-07-01'), end: new Date('2019-12-01') }

console.log(getOverlappingMonthsInterval(range1, range2)) // 5
```

---

I like to use the conditional operator for functions like this:

```js
// one-liner
const getOverlappingMonthsInterval = (r1, r2) =>
  areIntervalsOverlapping(r1, r2)
    ? differenceInCalendarMonths(
        min([r1.end, r2.end]),
        max([r1.start, r2.start])
      )
    : 0
```